# No implementation in C++ but can still call it

Tags: c++

I have `Simpletron.cpp` which is an **empty** file, a `Simpletron.h` which declares a `Simpletron` class:

```
class Simpletron 
{    
public:
    Simpletron();
};
```

I called `Simpletron()` in my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Simpletron.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    Simpletron s();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The main function just runs smoothly without any warning or error. Why is that? How does that even compile if there is no inplementation the header file could link to?

Comment: @Smac89: Not when you declare it. Maybe I'm going crazy, but at least 7 other people are wrong too. This program should cause a linker error, [example](http://ideone.com/5m0ygK).

Comment: @octef: Please provide your real code and command line. For example, your class definition is missing a semicolon after it so this can't be  the code you're compiling.

Comment: @GManNickG: [VC++ compiles it](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/pqw).  I think the issue is the most-vexing-parse, personally.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That would require a name: `Foo x();`. And technically that's just plain vexing. The "most" vexing parse refers to `Foo x(Foo());`.

Comment: @Smac89 That's not accurate at all, if he declared the default constructor but didn't implement he should get a linking error. The compiler will not generate a default constructor unless none is declared.

Comment: Adding the semicolon at the end of `Foo.h` and compiling with `g++ Foo.cpp -o Foo`, I get a link-time error: `Foo.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `Foo::Foo()'`

Comment: @MooingDuck my version of vc most certainly does not compile the provided code. A linking error is generated as one would expect. Maybe an old vc bug.

Comment: @MooingDuck your link seems to only compile to object file, but not linking.

Comment: @MooingDuck Exactly, I'm using VS 2012

Comment: Surprise surprise.  Your original example is completely different than your actual code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley uhh.. how is that the case? He just changed Foo to Simpletron and fixed the missing ';'

Comment: @BenjaminLindley What's the difference? I was just trying to use the universal class Foo and while modifying missed a semicolon.

Comment: @DanO: Look again.  `Foo();` vs. `Simpleton s();` -- One is a constructor call, the other is a function declaration.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm getting the same linking error regardless of the syntax I choose for the constructor call. This is not a vexing parse issue.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oh, you are right. My bad sorry.

Comment: Changing `Simpletron s();` to `Simpletron s;` triggers a linker error.

Comment: @DanO: Considering the fact that `Simpletron s();` isn't a constructor call, I don't really understand what you mean by "regardless of the syntax I choose for the constructor call".

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Aha, you are correct.

Comment: Everyone else knew that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This line:

```
Simpletron s();
```

is a function prototype, declaring a function named `s`, returning a `Simpletron` and taking no arguments. It does not create a `Simpletron` instance named `s`.

Now you might ask, why doesn't the linker complain about the non-existent `s()` function instead? Well, since you're only declaring `s()` but never actually calling it, it's not actually referenced anywhere during linking, so you get no link error.

Answer (score 13):

```
Simpletron s();
```

This is function declaration, not an object instantiation. The empty parenthesis tells the compiler this function takes no arguments and returns an object of type `Simpletron` by value, so no constructors are called. The correct syntax is without the parameters:

```
Simpletron s; // You will get an error on this line, as initially expected
```

C++11 adds a syntactical feature that avoids this ambiguity:

```
Simpletron s{}; // same as default-initialization
```

Comment: @MahanGM: Where "fix" means causing the code _to behave as expected_.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Simpletron s();
```

This is a classic case of "vexing parse"; for the compiler, you are not creating a variable `s` of type `Simpletron`, but you are declaring a function named `s`, taking no parameters and returning a `Simpletron` object.

This comes from the fact that this expression could be interpreted both as a function declaration and as a variable declaration; since to declare the variable there's an easy alternative (namely, just omit the parentheses) the standard mandates to interpret this as a function declaration.

This passes without problems the compiling phase (the compiler doesn't need to have the *definitions* of all the methods, just the declarations), and probably the linker doesn't give any error since no instance of `Simpletron` is actually created, so it never needs to actually look for the constructor definition (although I don't think that it's *guaranteed* not to give errors, a particularly thorough compiler/linker couple should be able to give you an error for the missing constructor anyway).