# printing value in constructor and destructor

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am stucked on the following code for constructors and destructors which I don't understand the result.one of the value should be 7 and how come there are four numbers? help appreciated.

```
  class Package
  {
       private:
       int value;
public:
    Package()
    {
        value=7;
        cout<<value<<endl;
    }
    Package(int v)
    {
        value=v;
        cout<<value<<endl;
    }
    ~Package()
    {
        cout<<value<<endl;
    }
  };
  int main()
  {
     Package obj1(4);
     Package obj2();
     Package obj3(2);
     return 0;
  }
```

in console prompt it displays

```
4
2
2
4
```

Answer (score 4):

This statement

```
 Package obj2();
```

is a function declaration that has no parameters and has return type of Package.

You could write instead

```
 Package obj2 {};
```

if you want that it would be an object definition.

So you defined only two objects

```
 Package obj1(4);
 Package obj3(2);
```

And correspondingly the constructors print

```
4
2
```

The destructor is called in the reverse order relative to called constructors (LIFO - last input first output) and outputs

```
2
4
```

Comment: Note that the fix `Package obj2 {};` is only valid starting from C++11.

Answer (score 2):

```
Package obj2();
```

exhibits what is called the [Most](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/) [Vexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets) [Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem in C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
Package obj2();
```

This line was parsed as "declare a function named `obj2` that returns a `Package` object," not as "declare a variable named `obj2` of type `Package` and construct it with no arguments."  This is called the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Fix for any C++:

```
Package obj2;
```

More explicit fix with C++11 syntax:

```
Package obj2{};
```