# How to call an array in the main function from a class in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, scope

I used to do it in high school but I haven't practised for a couple of years.
What I'm trying to do is create an array which will store 100 IDs from 1-100. (This is for a game where each item will be assigned one of these IDs to distinguish each item from one another)
This is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class items_class
{
public:
    items_class();
    ~items_class();
    static int item_ID[100];
};

items_class::items_class()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            item_ID[i] = i;
        }

}

int main()
{
    items_class items();

    for(int x=0;x<=100;x++)
        {
            cout << items.item_ID[x] << endl;
        }
}
```

but when I try to compile it I get this error:

> main.cpp:29:27: error: request for member 'item_ID' in 'items', which
>   is of non-class type 'items_class()'
>                cout << items.item_ID[x] << endl;

Can anyone tell me why this is occurring? It's probably really obvious but I can't figure it out and I have scoured the internet all night! Grr.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `items_class items();` -> `items_class items;` or `items_class items{};`

Comment: You forgot that C indices are offsets, and thus 0-based?

Comment: 0-based and ranged up to N-1 (including) !

Comment: The somewhat vexing parse again...`items_class items();` declares a function called `items` taking no argument and returning an `item_class`.

Comment: and also, statics must be defined, not only declared (but I guess you didn't want it to be static at all)

Comment: Why are you declaring the array as static?  As a static variable, all classes that inherit from `items_class` will share the same instance of the variable.

Comment: Thank you guys :) what does 0-based mean ?!?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think you mean that each *instance* of the class will share the variable (and you don't even need an instance to access it -- you have `items_class::item_ID` for that).

Comment: It works how I wanted it to now, Thank you so much :)

Comment: @LukeDavidThompson: 0-based means that for array declared like `item_ID[100];` the first element is `item_ID[0]` and last item is `item_ID[99]`, but you are iterating up to `item_ID[100]` which is beyond the range

Comment: Oh yeah! I completely forgot about that, schoolboy error. derp
also, I'm new to this site, so how do I upvote you?

Comment: @LukeDavidThompson: these are just comments, not answers, but no worries, noone posted answer as there are dozens of duplicates for your problem on SO

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise :s sorry!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default constructor with empty brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

Comment: Every time an items_class is constructed, the array is reinitialized. This is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you were missing, you declared your static variable but never defined it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class items_class
{
public:
    items_class();
    ~items_class();
    static int item_ID[100];
};

int items_class::item_ID[100]; // Need to define the static variable in a compilation unit.
items_class::items_class()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            items_class::item_ID[i] = i;
        }

}

int main()
{
    items_class items();

    for(int x=0;x<=100;x++)
        {
            cout << items_class::item_ID[x] << endl;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer assumed that the static variable is what you wanted.  Another approach is to remove the static keyword.  Then, when declaring items, remove the parens