# c++ - How do you get a "pointer to self" from within a class?

Tags: c++

In a method of an object of type `class A`, I handle an object of `class B` that has a public method `.join(*A)`.

I want my object of type `A` calling this `someObjectOfTypeB.join(*A)` method, to use a pointer to itself as the parameter.

```
void A::someMethod()
{
    B b();
    b.join(I want to a to use a pointer to itself as a parameter);
}

A a();
a.someMethod();
```

Upon further investigation, `this` was not the problem as I led myself to believe; and is indeed the correct way of doing what I wanted to do.

Comment: Isn't that what `this` was purposed for!?!

Comment: You are declaring `b` as a _function_ here, taking void and returning a `B`. Is this what you want?

Comment: `*A` is not a valid type. Did you mean `A*` for `join`'s parameter type, or did you mean that given a suitable expression `A`, `join` can be called as `join(*A)`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: If you actually read that article you'll see that this is _not_ the most vexing parse, and I wish people would stop spreading the myth that it is. It is merely related to the MVP.

Comment: @Werner, I suspect you have got confused by the error message due to declaring `B b()`, which does not do what you think it does (as the comment above says, it declares a function). Try `B b; b.join(this);` (N.B. that's `B b;` _not_ `B b();`)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I didn't say it _is_ the MVP, I just pointed to the wikipedia page which covers similar cases, but I've replaced the comment anyway. Do you have a better reference (such as an SO answer) for "that's not a default-initialization it's a function declaration"?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Unfortunately, silly people keep closing them as dupes of confused MVP questions, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets isn't too bad if you ignore the constant propagation of the same myth throughout its answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

```
void A::someMethod()
{
    B b;
    b.join(this);
}
```

As **@AndrewLazarus** and **@JonathanWakely** commented, use `B b;` instead of `B b()`. The later declares a function `b` without parameters which returns `B`, and that is not what you want.

Comment: This is actually saying: b.join(pointer to b); This is why I am posting, because I tried that :(

Comment: @Werner Do you mean `b.join(&b)`?

Comment: Perhaps... regardless, I want the paramter to be of a's own self, not b

Comment: @Werner `A`'s own self, within `A`, it `this`. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Werner: You misunderstand how it works. Inside `A::someMethod()`, `this` refers to the instance of class `A`.

Comment: Don't reference comments in answers - comments are transient and will be deleted at any time. Instead, adapt the words you're referring to into your own post.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As you wish :).