# Initializing a variable using default constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm pretty new to c++, i'm now trying to learn all the basics,
I know when default constructors are called, but when i tried different syntax it doesn't work like i expected.

Look at the following code:

```
class a;
class b();
class c(NULL);
```

'class' is a class i created with default constructor,
for a and c everything works well, but for b it just won't recognize the variable as a class member.

As i see it b and c are basically the same, what's wrong than?
Thanks!

Comment: You created a class called `class`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Almost spilled my coffee. Maybe I imagined the tone of incredulity.

Comment: I think you meant that *a and b* are basically the same, not *b and c*?

Answer (score 4):

Don't name your class "`class`", as it is a reserved name.

As for C++, if the constructor takes no parameters, you instantiate it using

```
Foo a;   // note, if you are using c++11, you can do Foo a{};
```

As opposed to:

```
Foo b();
```

Which actually does something totally unexpected*, and declares a function named `b` that returns a `Foo` instance.

As for `Foo c(null)`, it won't compile as there is no default constructor that takes an argument.

---

* It is referred to as *"the most vexing parse"*, though I find that to be an exaggeration. It can certainly catch you by surprise, but just knowing that you can declare a function prototype inside a function, should be enough to remove the "vexing" aspect.

In other words `int getMyInt();` is obviously a function prototype when placed outside any function definitions. However, since this is **also** the case when inside a function definition, `int getMyInt();` doesn't do anything it wouldn't normally do... which is to define a function prototype `getMyInt` that returns an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is interpreted as a declaration of a function taking no arguments and returning an object of type `class`.

<s>This is known as the [***most vexing parse***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets).</s> **Edit:** This is ***not*** the *most vexing parse*.

Comment: No, this is _not_ the most vexing parse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That seems to be the case actually. The accepted answer that I linked is providing some false information then.

Comment: This is the *somewhat vexing parse*. There are other parses which are more vexing! (e.g. `MyClass foo( OtherClass(x), OtherClass(y) );`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Hah, I accept this terminology :D