# Issue with template class -- "request for member '...' in '...', which is of non-class type '...<int>()'"

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting various related issues working with using a function of this templated class.

For the header I have:

```
template<typename T>
class Stats {
    public:
        Stats();
        std::vector<T> polyfit( const std::vector<T>&, const std::vector<T>&, int );
        std::vector<T> polyval( const std::vector<T>& oCoeff, const std::vector<T>& );
        QList<int> linearRegression(int, int, int);
        static QList<int> DFT(QList<int>,QList<int>);

};
```

And then for the function definition, I have:

```
template<typename T>
QList<int> Stats<T>::DFT(QList<int> samples,QList<int> freqs){
    ...
    ...
}
```

And then, this is where the issue occurs, in another class, I have this:

```
Stats<int> stats();
QList<int> DFTs = stats.DFT(chunks.at(i),freqs);
```

The issue occurs at the `stats.DFT()` line, and is currently

```
request for member 'DFT' in 'stats', which is of non-class type 'Stats<int>()'
     QList<int> DFTs = stats.DFT(chunks.at(i),freqs);
                             ^
```

Changing `Stats<int> stats()` to `Stats<int> stats` results in the following error:

```
undefined reference to `Stats<int>::Stats()'
```

The constructor definition is:

```
template<class T>
Stats<T>::Stats(){

}
```

---

The suggested answer does not use templates and the solution applied to this template class instantiation results in a new error.

Comment: Remove the `()` after `stats`. You are declaring a function.

Comment: @T.C. Which dup is better, that one or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/180172/2069064)?

Comment: @T.C. I tried that too, it results in `undefined reference to \`Stats<int>::Stats()'`

Comment: Well, did you actually write that constructor?

Comment: Yeah, the constructor is `template<class T>
Stats<T>::Stats(){

}`

Comment: My crystal ball says you didn't define that constructor in a header. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: It says `public: Stats();` Is there something else I have to do? `Stats<int>();` won't build.