# initialization of data types in a std vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, syntax-error

OK I am currently building a matrix using the std vectors that is meant to have a cell or bacteries on them. Because of this I made a "dead" class to be mother of cell and bacteries. So in the matrix a case that does not have either of them would be dead.

But when I try to build the matrix, by somthing like:  world[x][y] = new cell()/world[x][y] = new bacterie();  it will not compile.

so my question is, how can I initialize it?

this is my code, its on spanish sorry.

```
matrizB[fila-1][columna-1] =  new BacteriaM();
```

matrizB its a

```
vector<vector <dead>> matrizB(n);
```

and BacteriaM is a class that inherits from dead; n is defined by the user.
(sorry for bad grammar and programing, i'm new to programing)

Comment: `vector<vector <dead*>> matrizB(n);` you're missing the asterisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue that you are having is the `new` operator. I am assuming you are not accustomed to *C++* when it comes to creating objects. The [`new` operator for *C++*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx) does not simply create an object, but a pointer to an object. So, you can go `matrix[x][y] = cell()` or change to a `vector< vector < dead* > >` and follow what @Duthomhas says with selecting smart pointers. That way you can better manage memory especially when you are dealing with a vector of vectors.

[Note: Watch out for `cell()` constructors!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets) *C++* will get confused and think you are declaring a function...

Answer (score 1):

In order to use polymorphism, your matrix element must be a *pointer*.

```
vector<vector <dead*>> matrizB(n);
```

You will have to be careful to manage the memory of the elements. It might be worth looking at smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` -- whichever is more correct).

Hope this helps.