# Returning a vector of objects by value

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wondering if the following is a safe way of returning a deep `vector` of objects.

```
class MyClass {
    //...
}

std::vector<MyClass> get_list(a,b,c) {
    // obj is created on the stack
    MyClass obj(a,b,c);
    std::vector<MyClass> objects();
    objects.push_back(obj);
    // objects[0] contains a pointer to a stack variable?
    return objects
}
```

In particular, how does the returned vector not contain a reference to a stack memory location?

Answer (score 3):

Whether it's safe or not depends upon `MyClass`. But assuming it's a [well behaved class with value semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), then yes, it's perfectly safe. `std::vector` stores its objects by value. When you do this:

```
objects.push_back(obj);
```

A copy of `obj` is put into the vector (assuming you actually had a vector, [which you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)). And when you return the vector it is [moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) (though this move can be and usually is [optimized away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)) out to the calling function.

Comment: Thanks. In my case `MyClass` will contain some very large members data matrices as members. If things get copied, does that mean constructing `MyClass` via `MyClass(large_matrix)` is also a problem? When dealing with large objects what is the standard practice? Sorry, new to C++.

Answer (score 2):

**NO**.

```
objects.push_back(obj);
```

The local variable, i.e. obj, is **COPIED** into the vector. So the vector won't contain a reference to a local variable.

By the way, you CANNOT define a vector like this:

```
std::vector<MyClass> objects();
```

In fact, this is a function declaration: a function named objects, which has no parameter, and returns a std::vector.

Instead, you should do it like this:

```
std::vector<MyClass> objects;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, `objects.push_back(obj);` calls the `T const&` version of [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) which will *copy* the parameter.