# Request for member '...' in '...' which is of non-class type. But why?

Tags: c++

```
class automat_finit
{
    int CxQ, CxF, CxSigma, CxTranzitii, q0, SC, *F;
    char *Sigma;

    struct delta
    {
        int a1, a2;
        char c;
    }*G;

public:
    int tranzitie(int x, char c)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < CxTranzitii; i++)
            if((G[i].a1 == x) && (G[i].c == c))
                return G[i].a2;
        return -1;
    }

    automat_finit()
    {
        ifstream f("automatfinit.in");
        SC = 0;
        f >> CxQ;
        F = new int[CxF];
        for(int i = 0; i < CxF; i++)
            f >> F[i];
        Sigma = new char[CxSigma];
        for(int i = 0; i < CxSigma; i++)
            f >> Sigma[i];
        f >> CxTranzitii;
        G = new delta[CxTranzitii];
        for(int i = 0; i < CxTranzitii; i++)
            f >> G[i].a1 >> G[i].c >> G[i].a2;
        f.close();
    }

    bool citire(char *cuvant)
    {
        int l = strlen(cuvant);
        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            SC = tranzitie(SC, cuvant[i]);
            if(SC == -1) return false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < CxF; i++)
            if(SC == F[i]) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    automat_finit A();
    char w[100];
    cin>>w;
    if(A.citire(w) == true) cout<<"Word accepted"<<endl;
    else cout<<"Word denied"<<endl;
}
```

I get an error in `main` on line 64 with the 'citire' method, and I don't know why. It says

> error: request for member 'citire' in 'A', which is of non-class type 'automat_finit()'.

Also, if I declare object `A` instead of `A()`, I get bad alloc error. Why is that?

Comment: Also, the large list of linked questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180172/1896169) which could also be duplicate targets

Comment: For the next error: You input `CxQ`, but then use `CxF` and `CxSigma` for array sizes. What are those values?

Answer (score 0):

> It says "error: request for member 'citire' in 'A', which is of non-class type 'automat_finit()'.

It's what it says. `automat_finit A()` declares a function, not an object.

> If I declare object A instead of A()

Correct fix.

> I get bad alloc error. Why is that?

Because you have a bad allocation somewhere. Time to debug! Check your allocations. Check your `new`s. Check the variables you use to bound your `new`s. For example, where did you give `CxF` a meaningful value?

Comment: Oh, thanks. Now, I guess the problem is one of those 'new int' or 'new char' declarations.

Comment: @user8113290: Yes, I would imagine so.

Answer (score 0):

`automat_finit A();` declares a function named `A` that returns an `automat_finit` object.  If you want to declare an object named `A` of type `automat_finit`, you need to remove the panthesis:

```
automat_finit A;
```

As for the resulting memory allocation error, your `CxF` and `CxSigma` members are uninitialized when used by the `F = new int[CxF]` and `Sigma = new char[CxSigma]` statements, respectively.  Uninitialized class members have indeterminate values (unless the object is allocated in global memory, which is not the case in your situation).  By default, the `new` operator throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception when it fails to allocate the requested amount of memory.  Your members likely contain very large values by default, which you are not overwriting.

Comment: Nitpick: indeterminate, not random.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: fixed, thanks