# Constructor called with creating object

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initializer

```
class P{
    public:
    P(int x,int y) { cout << "constructor called" << endl;}
};

int main ()
{
    P(5,4);    // constructor called  
    P p(5,4);  // constructor called
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between the above two constructor calls?

How does `P(5,4)` call the constructor?

Comment: What are your doubts why the constructor shouldn't be called? The constructor function is called the same way for both examples.

Answer (score 3):

Those two invocations are identical.

The only difference is in the second you hold the created object in a local variable `p`

Answer (score 0):

In C++ a type name followed by a (possibly empty) parenthesized list is a prvalue expression that (usually) results in creation of a temporary object of that type, and the list consists of the arguments to the constructor.

An exception to this is when there is syntactic ambiguity, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets).

Compare with `P p = P(5,4);`   In `P(5,4);` you still have the same righthand side, but you just let the object be created and destroyed  instead of associating it with a name `p`.