# What is the difference between object creating types in c++?

Tags: c++

Assume that I have "A" class. I want to create an "a" object using that class with 2 different ways, i.e:

```
A a();
A a = A();
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: did you try and see any difference?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A a();` is not a variable declaration, it is a function declaration. It declares a function `a` that takes no parameters and returns an `A`.

`A a = A();` is a variable declaration and initialization.  It declares a variable `a` of type `A` and initializes it from the temp object that is created by explicitly calling `A`'s default constructor.  The simpler way to do this is `A a;` (note the lack of parenthesis!), which a smart compiler is likely to optimize `A a = A();` into anyway.  If you want to explicitly call the default constructor (if one is present), use curly brackets instead of parenthesis: `A a{};`

Comment: *which a smart compiler is likely to optimize A a = A(); into anyway.* starting in C++17 it is mandated to be the same. *thank you guaranteed copy elision*