# C++ 0/1-argument constructors not chaining as expected when passed to template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, type-erasure, template-argument-deduction, constructor-overloading

In the below code example, I have a class with a templatized 1-argument constructor, called `Acceptor1`.  I want to pass in objects of type `Foo, Bar, or Baz` to its constructor, chaining the constructor calls.  *(The reality is that this simplified example reflects something I am trying to do with type erasure: where I want to pass in an object to the eraser class.)*  What actually happens is that when I try to declare an `Acceptor1` object and pass it e.g. a `Foo` object, I define a variable that points to a function that accepts a FUNCTION pointer (not an `Foo` object) and returns an `Acceptor1`.  The type of the function pointer is `Foo(*)()`.  The overall variable is declared of type `Acceptor1 (Foo (*)())`.

I can't work around this with any possible `enable_if` statement, as shown by the `Accessor2` class example, where I didn't even **define** a 1-argument constructor.

Like I mentioned, the end-use of this is to be able to have a type eraser class that has a constructor looking like `Acceptor1`, plus the extra mechanics for type erasure.  I've done this and it works fine as long as the type I'm erasing isn't constructed with a 0/1-argument constructor.  Or, I can declare and assign the variables in two separate statements.  However, I have a lot of them, and this doubles the size of the code, plus takes up a few more CPU cycles, I guess.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get `Acceptor1 test( Foo() )` to be treated as defining an `Accessor1`, and initializing it with a `Foo` object?  It works fine with `Accessor1 test( Baz(d, d2) )`, a two-argument situation.  It also works fine with literals, e.g. `Acceptor1 test( Bar(1.0) )`.  Thanks!

Sean

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        cout << "Foo" << endl;
    }
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(double a) {
        cout << "Bar" << endl;
    }
};

struct Baz {
    Baz(double a, double b) {
        cout << "Baz" << endl;
    }
};

struct Acceptor1 {
    template<typename T> //no possible enable_if could help this problem
    Acceptor1(T f) {
        cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
    }
};

struct Acceptor2 {
};

int main()
{
    double d, d2;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    //0 arguments - captures a conversion constructor
    Acceptor1 one(Foo()); //F9Acceptor1PF3FoovEE=Acceptor1 (Foo (*)())
    cout << "one: " << typeid(one).name() << endl << endl;
    
    //0 arguments - the result we expect
    Acceptor1 two = Acceptor1(Foo()); //9Acceptor1=Acceptor1
    cout << "two: " << typeid(two).name() << endl << endl;

    //There's no possible way to enable_if it out - I deleted the whole constructor
    Acceptor2 three(Foo()); //F9Acceptor2PF3FoovEE=Acceptor2 (Foo (*)())
    cout << "three: " << typeid(three).name() << endl << endl;

    //1 arguments - captures a conversion constructor
    Acceptor1 four(Bar(d)); //F9Acceptor13BarE=Acceptor1 (Bar)
    cout << "four: " << typeid(four).name() << endl << endl;
    
    //1 arguments - the result we expect
    Acceptor1 five = Acceptor1(Bar(d)); //9Acceptor1=Acceptor1
    cout << "five: " << typeid(five).name() << endl << endl;

    //There's no possible way to enable_if it out - I deleted the whole constructor
    Acceptor2 six(Bar(d)); //F9Acceptor23BarE=Acceptor2 (Bar)
    cout << "six: " << typeid(six).name() << endl << endl;

    //1 arguments - literal
    Acceptor1 seven(Bar(5.0)); //9Acceptor1=Acceptor1
    cout << "seven: " << typeid(seven).name() << endl << endl;

    //2 arguments - the result we expect
    Acceptor1 eight(Baz(d, d2)); //9Acceptor1=Acceptor1
    cout << "eight: " << typeid(eight).name() << endl << endl;
    
    //2 arguments - the result we expect
    Acceptor1 nine = Acceptor1(Baz(d, d2)); //9Acceptor1=Acceptor1
    cout << "nine: " << typeid(nine).name() << endl << endl;

    using FooMaker = Foo(&)();
    using AcceptorFnToBazMaker = Acceptor1(*)(FooMaker); //PF9Acceptor1RF3FoovEE=Acceptor1 (*)(Foo (&)())
    cout << "AcceptorFnToBazMaker: " << typeid(AcceptorFnToBazMaker).name() << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: It was suggested that this is a duplicate of [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets) - I agree that they both mention the "most vexing parse" as the source of the problem, but the questions are different.  The answer there even includes an example with a function of 2 parameters.  In my case, with constructors, only 0/1-argument constructors are treated specially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Acceptor1 test( Foo() )` to `Acceptor1 test((Foo()))` or an even better way would be `Acceptor1 test{Foo()}` or perhaps (as you did) `Acceptor1 test = Acceptor1(Foo())`;

The compiler can interpret the line as a valid function declaration and an object initialization. The standard (as far as I remember) says that in such a case, take it as a function declaration. Here's what's [in cppreference about this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) :

> In case of ambiguity between a variable declaration using the direct-initialization syntax (1) (with round parentheses) and a function declaration, the compiler always chooses function declaration. This disambiguation rule is sometimes counter-intuitive and has been called the most vexing parse.

And hence you get this.

To make the compiler interpret this as an object initilization, add a parathesis `()` around to make it an invalid function declaration. Viz-a-viz, all you have to do is to make sure it's not a valid function declaration syntax.

Comment: Thanks much!  I don't suppose you know where in the standard that behavior is defined, or even a web reference.  Will mark as answered (in no time!).

Comment: @Sean added reference from cppreference, which I believe should be a valid and sufficient source of truth.

Comment: I'd add an upvote if I wasn't too new.  Thanks.