# Simple Class and Header in Separate File Won't Work

Tags: c++, class, oop, header

I'm currently learning c++ for a week and here's my problem:

**run.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Abc.h"

int main(){
    int a;
    std::cout << "Enter a : ";
    std::cin >> a;

    // Object Initialization
    Abc AbcObj();
}
```

the header, **Abc.h** :

```
#ifndef ABC_H
#define ABC_H


class Abc
{
    public:
        Abc();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // ABC_H
```

and finally my cpp file for implementation, **Abc.cpp**:

```
#include "Abc.h"
#include <iostream>

Abc::Abc()
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Object created ";
}
```

Why don't I get output on my console? I'm expecting "object created" should be on the console. These files are in the same directory.

Comment: `Abc AbcObj();` - that is not constructor calling. It's fucntion prototype. You need just `Abc AbcObj;`

Comment: what if I need an argument for the constructor? @EOF

Comment: If constructor can accepts arguments: `Abc AbcObj(arg);`

Comment: I got `undefined reference` error bro..

Comment: Your constructor does not accepts argument. You need create another constructor)

Comment: no, I've tried `Abc AbcObj`, and resulting `undefined reference`

Comment: Are you compiling two files?

Comment: I just compile the `run.cpp`, the main file

Comment: `g++ run.cpp Abc.cpp -o your_prog_name`

Comment: Still no output from the constructor sir...

Comment: https://ideone.com/wIj2U6

Comment: go through [variable Initialization – or Is It?](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error doesn't come up because you've used different files, so I have used one in this example

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    Foo()
    {
       std::cout << "Constructor called!";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo obj();
}
```

Why don't you see the message? [You can read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

The problem here is, `Foo obj()` is taken as a [function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function). To fix this you need to remove the `()`

```
int main()
{
    Foo obj;
}
```

> Constructor called!